# Hibernate issue on saveorupdate an object but it cant execute the db trigger

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using a mssql database and a table called `test` with insert and update trigger.

When I disable the trigger in `test` table, I can save the record through the hibernate `saveorupdate` event.

When I enable the trigger in `test` table, I can't save the record through the hibernate `saveorupdate` event and it's prompt a connection timeout problem after 300 seconds.

I have tried to insert the record by sql insert statement for testing purpose. It's work properly and no exceptions on my trigger.

How can I solve the above problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: It caused by the hibernate cross database problem because the trigger will call store procedure in another database schema.